# Use component onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want a component with a alert function to be activated when clicking on a button in a class-component.

#### My Functional Component

```
import React from 'react'

export default function ConfirmationModal() {

    alert = () => {
        alert("whatsup hotdawg?")
    }

  return (
    <div>
        {this.alert()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### In Class Component

i have this line that i would like to trigger the Alert method in the functional component onClick

```
<button>"ClickMe" onClick=<ConfirmationModal/> </button>
```

Any suggestions on how i can perform this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements, can u elaborate more?

Comment: My Apologies,
Imagine having two components and in one of them you have a OnClick that calls the second component.
The second component can render anything. I'm just uncertain of how to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep a piece of state in your parent component called e.g. `isModalOpen` that you set to true when clicking the button, and use this piece of state to conditionally render the `ConfirmationModal`.

It's also a good idea to not call methods directly on render, since that will occur on every render. You can move the alert to `componentDidMount` instead.

**Example**

```js
class ConfirmationModal extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    alert("whatsup hotdawg?");
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Modal</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isModalOpen: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ isModalOpen: true })}>
          Click me
        </button>
        {this.state.isModalOpen && <ConfirmationModal />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

React is Component based library, So add your ui component(button) and associated logic in the same component.

Change your functional Component to following.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ConfirmationModal extends React.Component {

    alert = () => {
        alert("whatsup hotdawg?")
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.alert}>"ClickMe"</button>
        )
    }
}
```

And in your class component import the above component and use it.
Your Class Component should look something like this.

```
render(){
     return (
          <ConfirmationModal />
     )
}
```